# LG UltraFine & replacement Belkin USB-C cable gives blurry text

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, font, text

I have an **LG UltraFine 5K screen** and a **2016 15-inch MacBook Pro**.

The original USB-C cable that came with the screen broke. So I bought a **Belkin USB-C** replacement. Now all **text is noticeable blurry.** So it’s not fully compatible despite the fact that I bought everything directly from Apple.

Are there any **settings** I can try to tweak to get the same sharp text like with the original cable? I’ve already tried disabling font smoothing. If not, **which cable I should buy** to get full compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [specs of the the LG 5K Display](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27MD5KA-B-5k-uhd-led-monitor#pdp_spec) and the accessories (cable) it comes with, you can't just use any plain USB-3 cable.

[image]

You need a [Thunderbolt 3 Active Cable](http://radnex.us/thunderbolt-3-active-cable).  [Thunderbolt 1 and 2](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/usb-type-c-thunderbolt-3-one-cable-to-connect-them-all/), natively, were active meaning power was required to operate properly.  Normally, Thunderbolt 3 is a passive, meaning power isn't present. Any *quality* USB-3 cable will carry Thunderbolt 3 (and vice versa).

However, to drive this particular monitor, it appears LG requires an active cable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The Belkin USB-C cable does charge the computer, so I guess it’s active? The only issue is the pixelated text. So maybe the cable is simply faulty.

Comment: It has to say active.  An active Thunderbolt 3 cable is much for expensive than a regular Thunderbolt 3 cable. The [Belkin TB3 cable](https://amzn.to/2ZVRib7)  is about $30 where as the [Belkin *Active* cable](https://amzn.to/2CiIeF3) is $70